# Should the food pyramid question be closed?

Tags: discussion

This question https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/167/does-the-current-food-pyramid-outline-good-dietary-choices asks about the 2010 food pyramid and asks if it falls short of its aims or provides inaccurate information.

As the pyramid has now been replaced by ChooseMyPlate, it has obviously been superseded. I guess we could examine the 2010 pyramid as it was, but I think that because it has been superseded that it is no longer noteworthy. With a likely answer along the line of it doesn't meet current understanding and expectations and thus was replaced.

I have personally voted to close as too localized as the event has passed. What do others think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It’s now too localised, and has been closed.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to answer here when I closed it.